# Finding approximation to stable manifold of saddle point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, dynamical-systems

I am stuck on the following exercise from Strogatz' book on dynamical systems (exercise 6.1.14).

> Consider the system $\dot{x} = x+e^{-y}, \dot{y} = -y$. This system
>   has a single fixed point, $(-1, 0)$. This is a saddle point. The
>   unstable manifold is $y=0$, but the stable manifold is some non-linear
>   curve. Let $(x, y)$ be a point on the stable manifold close to $(-1,
> > 0)$ and define $u = x + 1$. Write the stable manifold as $y=a_1u +a_2u^2 + O(u^3)$. To determine the coefficients, derive two
>   expressions for $dy/du$ and equate them.

I have, as a first try for an equation, simply differentiated $y$ wrt $u$: $\frac{dy}{du} = a_1 + 2a_2u + O(u^2)$, where I'm a bit uncertain about the $O(u^2)$, but I suspect we can leave that out anyway, since we're approximating. I'm not sure how we'd find a second equation.

[I've found a post that answers the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843897/strogatz-exercise-6-1-14-how-to-approximate-stable-manifold-of-a-saddle-point-w), but it ends up with a line, rather than the non-linear curve that is pictured in the book:
[image]

Furthermore, I don't see why they have $\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{u}}$ or how they calculated the Taylor approximation for $\dot{u}$.

Basically, I'm a bit lost, could someone perhaps give me some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}u} = \frac{{\rm d}y / {\rm d}t}{{\rm d}u / {\rm d}t} \tag{1}
$$

If you replace

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = -y \tag{2}
$$

and

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t} = \frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} = u - 1 + \left(1 - y + \frac{y^2}{2} - \cdots \right) \tag{3}
$$

In (1) you will get

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}u} = -\frac{y}{u - y + y^2/2 - y^3/6 + \cdots} \tag{4}
$$

Now you replace your expression for $y$: $y(u) = a_1u + a_2 u^2 + \cdots$. I'm going to take another path to the solution you just linked, and expand the result to a higher order, you do this by replacing the expression for $y$ in (4) and Taylor expanding it around $u = 0$, the result is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}u} &=& \frac{a_1}{a_1 - 1} + \frac{a_1^3 - 2 a_2 }{2(a_1 - 1)^2}u + \frac{2a_1^4 + a_1^5 - 18a_1^2 a_2 + 12 a_2^2 + 12 a_3 - 12 a_1 a_3}{12(a_1 - 1)^3}u^3 + \cdots \\
&=& a_1 + 2a_2 u + 3a_3 u^3 + \cdots
\end{eqnarray}

You solve for coefficients, and you should get

$$
a_1 = 2,~~ a_2 = 4/3, ~~a_3 = 10/9
$$

The black line below is the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How did you find the Taylor expansion around $u=0$? If I substitute the equation for $y(u)$ into $(4)$, I get a function of $u$ that is $0$ for $u=0$, rather than the constant term $\frac{a_1}{a_1-1}$ you find.

Comment: @Dasherman It will be zero in the numerator *and* in the denominator, take the limit when $u\to 0$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! I only checked the numerator. Do you also happen to know what the 'correct' way is to treat the $O(u^3)$ term when we do an approximation like this? Should I treat it as $0$ or should I treat it as a term $a_3u^3$?

Comment: @Dasherman It means just to truncate the series at $u^2$, ignore the higher order terms. In my solution above I actually went up to $u^3$ and ignored $u^4$, $u^5$, $\cdots$

Comment: When I solve for $a_1$ I find two possible solutions, 0 and 2, why do you pick 2 rather than 0?

Comment: @Dasherman Because if you select the root $a_1 = 0$ you will see that $a_2 = 0$, $a_3 = 0$